# Specify T in a property

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have at the moment:

```
public HashSet<int> UniqueData { get; private set; }
```

If another property is set I want to make it

```
public HashSet<string> UniqueData { get; private set; }
```

so in the constructor it becomes

```
if (MyProperty)
  UniqueData = new HashSet<string>();
else
  UniqueData = new HashSet<int>();
```

Is there a way to declare the property as:

```
  public HashSet<T> UniqueData { get; private set; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot declare two properties that differ only in type. You can use the `HashSet<T>` syntax if you make your entire class generic on `T`.

```
class Example<T> {
    public HashSet<T> Unique {get;set;}
    public Example(HashSet<T> hs) {
        Unique = hs;
    }
}
public static void Main() {
    Example<int> a = new Example<int>(new HashSet<int>());
    Example<string> b = new Example<string>(new HashSet<string>());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately No there is no way you can do that. Property datatypes have to be declared at compile time.

Make a class whose type is `T` and assign that `T` to property's `T`

```
public class TClass<T>
{
    public HashSet<T> UniqueData { get; set; } 
}
```

and call it like

```
public static void Main() 
{
    TClass<int> a = new TClass<int>(){ UniqueData = new HashSet<int>()};
    TClass<string> b = new TClass<string>(){ UniqueData = new HashSet<string>()};
}
```

Moreover if its `private set` you can only set its value from inside class.

Answer (score 1):

You will likely have to do this at the class level to get a return type of `HashSet<T>`

```
public class MyClass<T>
{

  #region ctors
  public MyClass()
  {
    this.UniqueData = new HashSet<T>();
  }
  #endregion

  public HashSet<T> UniqueData { get; private set; } 
}
```

Usage:

```
MyClass cint = new MyClass<int>();
cint.UniqueData.Add(1);

MyClass cstr = new MyClass<string>();
cstr.UniqueData.Add("something unique");
```

Comment: oops... forgot the constructor for the private set.

Answer (score 0):

`public HashSet<object> UniqueData { get; private set; }`. The type must be specified at compile-time, so no, strong typing system isn't your friend in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there is an error in your design. Which features of HashSet do you want to use in the rest of your program that are not related to the type of data stored in your Hash set?

Then expose those features of the HashSet (e.g. by an Adapter class or by a set of properties), not the HashSet itself.

Comment: Then you might solve the problem by making your class generic and deriving from a non-generic base class for those things which do not depend on the type of the hash set.

Comment: I only use it in 2 places, one to add to it and one to read the last value from it. What I might do is make it generic and then test the type when it takes the last item because at that point it does lastvalue minus 999, obviously cannot do it for a string. Might be a tad over complicated your way